# about php, but I don't know how to make it check whether the product already exists or not

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have problem cant exist catogaries :
I want chek if the catogary is add before or not
please i need help
I have problem cant exist catogaries :
I want chek if the catogary is add before or not
please i need help
I have problem cant exist catogaries :
I want chek if the catogary is add before or not
please i need help
I have problem cant exist catogaries :
I want chek if the catogary is add before or not
please i need help
I have problem cant exist catogaries :
I want chek if the catogary is add before or not
please i need help
I have problem cant exist catogaries :
I want chek if the catogary is add before or not
please i need help
I have problem cant exist catogaries :
I want chek if the catogary is add before or not
please i need help

```
<?php
require '0.php';
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
  $catogary_name = $_POST['catogary-name'];
  $catogary_much = $_POST['catogary-much'];

  
  if (empty($catogary_name) == true || empty($catogary_much) == true){
  

  }else{
   
  

    
    
        $sql = "insert into catograyies (CATOGRARY,howMush) VALUES (' $catogary_name','$catogary_much')";
    
        
    
    
    
    if ($sq->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      
      } else {
        
      }  
  }
  header("location:");
  exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Make `category` a unique column. Then you'll get an error if the column already exists.

Comment: I dont want error if  THE ADMIN ADD catogary i just want cant add catogary twice

Comment: Do this query first: `SELECT 1 FROM catograyies WHERE CATOGRARY = ?` and see if it returns any rows.

Comment: I try with this but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `SELECT` query first to check if the category already exists.

```
<?php
require '0.php';
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
    $catogary_name = $_POST['catogary-name'];
    $catogary_much = $_POST['catogary-much'];
  
    if (empty($catogary_name) == true || empty($catogary_much) == true){
    }else{
        $stmt = $sq->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM catograyies WHERE CATOGRARY = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $catogary_name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "Category $catogary_name already exists";
        } else {
            $stmt = $sq->prepare("insert into catograyies (CATOGRARY,howMush) VALUES (?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $catogary_name, $catogary_much);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
            } else {
            }
        }
    }
    header("location:");
    exit;
}
?>
```

I've also shown how to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables into the SQL, to protect against SQL-injection.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a select first. Here is an example below, this won't work out the box but will give you an idea what todo.

```
<?php
require '0.php';
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
  $catogary_name = $_POST['catogary-name'];
  $catogary_much = $_POST['catogary-much'];

  if (empty($catogary_name) || empty($catogary_much) ){
  

  } else {
    $checkExistsQuery = sprintf("SELECT id FROM catograyies WHERE CATOGRARY = %s", $catogary_name);
    $checkExists = $sq->query($checkExists);
    
    if (count($checkExists) > 0) {
      return 'Already Exists'
    }
    
    $sql = "insert into catograyies (CATOGRARY,howMush) VALUES (' $catogary_name','$catogary_much')";
    
    if ($sq->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      
      } else {
        
      }  
  }
  
  header("location:");
  exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: You're missing quotes around the category name. But you should use prepared statements, not string formatting.

Comment: I do like this before but not work and I am try now again I do like this but not work

  ` $checkExists = sprintf("SELECT * FROM catograyies WHERE CATOGRARY = %s", $catogary_name);
        
if ($checkExists > 0) {
 echo 'CATOGRARY already exists';
}else{
    $sql = "insert into catograyies (CATOGRARY,howMush) VALUES ('$catogary_name','$catogary_much')";

        

        
        if ($sq->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($sq);
        } `

Comment: I want to learn about php and sql becuase i see new info in this codes

Comment: Keep learning and you'll pick it up.
Some Good Resources:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/
https://www.learn-php.org/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/index.htm